# why is node https request faster than http request

Tags: node.js, performance-testing

I have the below code and i ran a performance test on post using http and https url. The result actually surprised me. https request are performing better.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs =require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var authTransaction = require('./routes/trans');
var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(mykey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('mycert.pem', 'utf8');
var passphrase ="blahblah";

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate,passphrase:passphrase};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(9090);
var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(5000);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send("hello ");
})

app.post('/trans', function(req,res){
    var purchase= new Purchase(req.body);
    purchase.save(function(err){
        if(err) {
            res.send({'error': 'An error occured'});
        }else{
                res.json({
                  "status": {
                        "message": [
                        "Success"
                        ]
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I ran 10 Threads for 1 hour, results below

The results:

NodeJS – https

```
Test    Min  Max    Avg   Last  Count      Throughput      Bytes     BPS    
Trans   5   3017    12.69   7     47010        13.05    13961970    3878
```

NodeJS – http

```
Test    Min Max     Avg    Last Count   Throughput  Bytes   BPS 
Trans   17  3031    40.26   29  45326   12.59    13461822   3739
```

Can anyone throw some light in here ?

Answer (score 1):

SSL handshake is shortened when the same client reconnects again and again (see [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Resumed_TLS_handshake)
) so to give an accurate picture you need to test from across a variety of client processes and machines.